# how it works pagination in prestashop?

Tags: pagination, prestashop

I have done some modification and now need to build my own pagination.

So i know prestashop have his own so how can i use them?

I was trying to use in classes/controller/FrontController.php

Use function:

```
public function pagination($nbProducts = 10)
        {....
```

But can't understand well where and how is formed a pagination itself... i think my php knowledgment is low so i need some help if somebody get understand how is pagination of Prestashop works.

Comment: The pagination is formed in themes/your_theme_name/pagination.tpl . There you can see the html and smarty code for that pagination.

Comment: i undestand that, but i need to undestand how it works in Controller, i mean how i can (if this is possible) use my own pagination for my own list of products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Front Controller assign products and the number of products in **smarty variables** for the page you want to see.
Here the example with BestSales Page in **BestSalesController** :

```
$nbProducts = (int)ProductSale::getNbSales();
$bestSales = ProductSale::getBestSales($this->context->language->id, $this->p - 1, $this->n, $this->orderBy, $this->orderWay);
....
// then assign it to smarty
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
     'nbProducts' => $nbProducts,
     'products' => $bestSales
));
```

There is nothing special or custom things you can do in Front Controller.

If you want to make a custom pagination, take a look at the **blocklayered** module.

For example, in *modules/blocklayered/blocklayered.php* at `ajaxCall()` function, you can specify custom choices for 'the number of products by page' by editing this line :

```
$nArray = (int)Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE') != 10 ? array((int)Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE'), 10, 20, 50) : array(10, 20, 50);
```

This line display 10, 20, 50 and default number of products per page specified in *Back-Office/Preferences/Products* but you can change it as your wish, example :

```
$nArray = array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60);
```

If you want to make customizations, you have to made them in this module, but it wouldn't be simple (the file is hitting 4200 lines, so good luck !).

Comment: thank you, i was not clear enough, but i was need to make my own pagination based in existent in Prestashop, but now i understand is not possible without to write my own code in override.